# get both by ID and Name in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

**In MySQL Database Table there are 2 columns**

> 1. Order TypeID
> 2. Order Type

**In Order to find a record with ID, I am using below code.**

```
$OrderType = \App\Models\OrderType_Model::find($request->input('OrderTypeID'));
```

**Is there any way to get both by ID and Name ?**

Comment: Pass an array to the find method, which includes order typeId and type

Comment: Did you refer to the http://laravel.com/docs/5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$OrderType = \App\Models\OrderType_Model
                ::where("OrderTypeID", "!=", $request->input('OrderTypeID'))
                ->where("OrderType",    '=', $request->input('OrderType'))->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a orWhere clause

```
$orderType = OrderType_Model
            ->where('OrderTypeId',$request->input('OrderTypeId))
            ->orWhere('OrderType', $request->input('OrderType))
            ->first();
```